# Calling functions from mongoose begin_request_handler callback

Tags: c, callback, mongoose-web-server

Currently I'm working on an application which embeds the mongoose webserver. In some cases, I have to call additional functions inside the `begin_request_handler` to create the desired HTTP header. During this, I realized that theses functions are called **after** the request handler is done. For example:

```
void test() {
    printf("HELLO");
}   

static int begin_request_handler(struct mg_connection *conn) {
    test();
    const struct mg_request_info *request_info = mg_get_request_info(conn);
    ...
    return 1;
}
```

Here the HELLO is getting printed right after the browser closes the tcp connection. Is there even a way to call functions from inside the callbacks? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to create the desired HTTP header. Then the function you mentioned above `(begin_request_handler)` may not be the correct approach. Look into the structure `mg_request_info` which is field in structure `mg_connection`. Here the name and value of headers is set.
   I think these structures are populated at the very start after connection establishment. Also look at `pull()` and `read()`. These are ground-level function where all data is set.
2. And yes there is a way to call functions from callbacks.You can write your own callback and make callback function to point in  struct of `mg_context` to make it point to your callback.
   and then in `handle_request()` you can call it appropriately. You can add it to `struct mg_callbacks` in mongoose.h

Example:

> memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));
> callbacks.begin_request => begin_request_handler;
>
> //place your function in place of begin_request_handler
> // Start the web server.
>
> ctx = mg_start(&callbacks, NULL, options);

Please specify any more details you maybe interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, got it. I got confused by the printf() buffers in stdout. The methods ARE called at the right time, yet the results aren't shown. Thank anyways.